# How to convert from Int to Double?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that takes a double as input but I have to pass an Int to it and it is giving me this error:

No instance for No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’

Here are my functions:

```
foo1 :: Int  -> Int
foo1 x1 = foo2 (x1 + 1)

foo2 :: Double -> Int
foo2 x = round (((3244325 * x^343)/2352352656) - ((3432 * x^234)/45324645500) + ((23453 * x^21)/2534743435)
```

I am not sure how to get around this problem.

Does something like the following exist:

```
foo1 :: Int  -> Int
foo1 x1 = foo2 $ convertToDouble $ (x1 + 1)
```

Comment: I don't know about Haskell, but I found this; check if it helps: "The usual way to convert an Int to a Double is to use fromIntegral, which has the type (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b. This means that it converts an Integral type (Int and Integer) to any numeric type b, of which Double is an instance."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `fromIntegral`:

```
 (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

It will convert an integral type (i.e. an Int, Integer, etc.) into another Num type.

Comment: None intuitive name haha

Comment: @user6005857 why? You probably are just *used*  to saying where you want to go instead of where you are coming from - but when the compiler knows the destination already ...

Comment: True, it makes sense.